# Date comparison in Query function not returning result

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am using the  below query

```
=QUERY(fulldata,"select avg(C) where A<>'Saturday'")
```

My Data looks like -

```
+-----------+-----------+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     A     |     B     | C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |  G  | H |  I  |  J  |  K  |  L  |  M  |
+-----------+-----------+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Sunday    | 1- Jan-18 |  6 |  12 |   0 | 1.5 | 2.5 | 2 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| Monday    | 2- Jan-18 |  6 |   0 | 9.5 |   4 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 2.5 |   2 |   0 |   0 |
| Tuesday   | 3- Jan-18 |  7 |   0 |   7 |   0 |   0 | 2 |   0 |   4 |   1 |   3 |   0 |
| Wednesday | 4- Jan-18 |  7 | 1.5 |   6 | 1.5 |   0 | 0 |   0 |   2 | 0.5 | 5.5 |   0 |
| Thursday  | 5- Jan-18 |  8 |   1 | 7.5 |   0 |   0 | 2 |   0 | 1.5 |   1 |   3 |   0 |
| Friday    | 6- Jan-18 | 14 |   6 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 2 |   0 | 1.5 | 0.5 |   0 |   0 |
| Saturday  | 7- Jan-18 |  9 | 0.5 |   0 | 0.5 | 1.5 | 2 | 3.5 | 4.5 | 0.5 | 1.5 | 0.5 |
+-----------+-----------+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

However I get no response from the query. The query runs without any issue but no results.

I simply want to find the **average of C** when **A is not Saturday** . Can anyone point where my query and/or logic is going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

My **Day** column was using `=DAY(Col B)` which was resulting into **Sun, 31 Dec 99** but it was displaying it as **Sunday** because of the formatting done from toolbar.

So when I was comparing it with Saturday/Sunday it wasn't matching and hence no results.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the optional headers argument too (1 or 0).

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE CHECK BELOW.

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select avg(C) where A NOT CONTAINS 'Saturday'")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me @shashank padelkar's A seems not to work, but the following does:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select avg(C) where not (A CONTAINS 'Saturday')")
```

(Assumes `Sunday` is in Row1.)

Mind you, so does OP's version work for me with `fulldata` replaced by `A:C`. So perhaps the real issue is something like trailing spaces or referencing the source. Also works for me if A1:M7 is named `fulldata`.